# Nokogiri Scraping Multiple URLS on Same Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape multiple urls with Nokogiri that are on the same domain. For example cltampa.com/potlikker and cltampa.com/artbreaker. For both urls I am looking for the same two elements, the main header image for every blog post and the url of the headline. I have code that is working for grabbing images, but it is very inefficient and definitely not DRY. I need to grab the associated headline hrefs as well, so I can then wrap the images with them in my view.

My controller currently looks like this

```
    def index
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://cltampa.com/blogs/potlikker'))
      potlikker = doc.xpath('//*[@class="contentImageCenter"]/img/@src')
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://cltampa.com/blogs/artbreaker'))
      artbreaker = doc.xpath('//*[@class="contentImageCenter"]/img/@src')
      @images = potlikker + artbreaker
    end
```

My view looks like this

```
<div id="container" class="container">
  <% @images.each do |img|%>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="<@url_should_go_here" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.cltampa.com<%= img %>"></a>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My first question is what is the most efficient way to parse multiple urls, because what I have now is not it. Would I create a separate method for that, any help on this would be awesome.

My next question is how would I grab the headline href at the same time as grabbing the image url. I have the xpath to grab both of them separately, but putting them together and then rendering them in my view is confusing me.

I've been referencing this answer [Iterating through multiple URLs to parse HTML with Nokogori](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453115/iterating-through-multiple-urls-to-parse-html-with-nokogori) but haven't had any luck yet.

Thanks in advance.

PROGRESS UPDATE

```
  def index
    urls = %w[http://cltampa.com/blogs/potlikker http://cltampa.com/blogs/artbreaker http://cltampa.com/blogs/politicalanimals http://cltampa.com/blogs/earbuds http://cltampa.com/blogs/bedpost http://cltampa.com/blogs/dailyloaf]
    @final_images = []
    @final_urls = []

    urls.each do |url|
      blog = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) 
      images = blog.xpath('//*[@class="contentImageCenter"]/img/@src')
      images.each do |image|
        @final_images << image
      end
    end  

    urls.each do |url|
      blog = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) 
      story_path = blog.xpath('//*[@class="postTitle"]/a/@href')
      story_path.each do |path|
        @final_urls << path
      end
    end 
  end
```

The above code is technically giving me what I need, just not sure on how to tie them together in the view. I need to wrap the final_urls around the final_images. I am sure there is a better way to do this, any info again is appreciated.

I should also add that I am experiencing a timeout on Heroku, so any advice on speeding this up, moving to a background task etc. would be very much appreciated. I am looking into it now, but not exactly sure the best route to take.

Comment: Does Heroku allow outgoing TCP connections? (Last time I checked they didn't, that would explain the timeout). Not sure what you mean by wrapping, but if you simply want to iterate over both arrays `@final_urls.zip(@final_images).each do |url, img|` should get you going.

Comment: Thank you @Matt, your code is exactly what I needed. I am not sure about the TCP connection issue, but would you suggest using something other than Heroku?

Comment: If you need full control over the networking aspects (which you usually want for a scraper) I can recommend DigitalOcean, AWS (or any other VPS hosting for that matter). Hope that helps.

Comment: @matt thanks again, I've been thinking about getting started with Digital Ocean, now seems like a good time.